# Setting second level javascript object to variable

Tags: javascript, object, web-applications, multidimensional-array

Trying to create a multi-level object, but not sure why the following won't work:

```
var a = {};
var b = 'Apples';
var c = 'Oranges';
a[b][c] = 'Test B';
alert(a[b][c]);
```

Is there a different way that I should be setting `a[b][c]`?

http://jsfiddle.net/zedsaid/acWNq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before working with multi-level objects you need to imagine how object literal will look like:

```
var a = {
    Apples : {
        Oranges : "Test B"
    }
}
```

Then you'll see that there is a need to "declare" a new level by initializing the new object `{}` for `a[b]`:

```
var a = {},
    b = "Apples",
    c = "Oranges";

a[b] = {};
a[b][c] = "Test B";
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I am used to PHP where I don't have to do that. Really appreciate your help!